# Adding custom server options with puppetlabs mysql module

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a puppet manifest that contains this phrase (my question is about the production block at the end), used to set up mysql configuration files:

```
class web_mysql_server {

  include web_mysql::packages
  include web_mysql::mysql_server
}

class web_mysql::packages {

  Package { ensure => installed }
  package { 'libmysqlclient-dev': }
}

class web_mysql::mysql_server {

# Qualified keys (dot notation: web_mysql_server.mysql_database) isn't available
  # until hiera 2.0.
  $mysql_config = hiera('web_mysql_server')

  # https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mysql
  class { '::mysql::server':
root_password => '...',
remove_default_accounts => true,
override_options        => {
  # The data in this block gets written to /etc/mysql/my.cnf.
  'mysqld'     => {
    max_connections => '1024', # No good reason but parroting others.
    key_buffer_size => '512M', # No good reason but parroting others.
  },

  'production' => {
    adaptor  => 'mysql2',
    database => $mysql_config['mysql_database'],
    user     => $mysql_config['mysql_username'],
    password => $mysql_config['mysql_password'],
    host     => '0.0.0.0',
    encoding => 'UTF8',
  },
```

But sometimes I'd maybe like the database to be a staging database, and so it's a bit confusing to call it production.  No problem, I've recently learned about hiera, it's my hammer for all nails today:

```
  $mysql_config['mysql_name'] => {
    adaptor  => 'mysql2',
    database => $mysql_config['mysql_database'],
    user     => $mysql_config['mysql_username'],
    password => $mysql_config['mysql_password'],
    host     => '0.0.0.0',
    encoding => 'UTF8',
  },
```

No, that doesn't work, though the error `("syntax error at line (...with '=>'...), expected '}'"`) isn't terribly revealing.

("Key" might be the wrong word.  Please correct me.  I'm a bit new to puppet.  And that itself may be why I've not been able to answer this question by googling and reading.)

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: it appears that you pass `production` as a parameter to a class or resource, right? Can you post the larger context including the class/resource?

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. Inside a class definition, such as `web_mysql::mysql_server`, you can include/declare resources, other classes, assign to variables, etc. The `'production' => { ... }` piece of code is neither. What do you expect this piece of code to do?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I just can't dereference a hash in that context.  If, instead, I assign `$mysql_section = $mysql_config[''mysql_name'"]`, then I can name the section `"${mysql_db_tab}" => ... `.  The quotes (single or double) are essential, though the error message doesn't make that very clear to me.

Comment: My intentions and execution could be wrong in so many ways, but what it does is to write a `[production]` section to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` with those entries.

Comment: (It's a key-value pair in the `override_options` hash, no?

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223202) :) . If creating a configuration file is what you need all along, see my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111974/discussion-between-jma-and-mifeet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I see now that the `mysql` module provides an option to add section to the config file out of the box. Here is how it should be used according to the [documentation](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/mysql#setup):

```
$override_options = {
  $mysql_config['mysql_name'] => {
    adaptor => 'mysql2',
    database => $mysql_config['mysql_database']
    # ...
  }
}

class { '::mysql::server':
  root_password           => 'strongpassword',
  remove_default_accounts => true,
  override_options        => $override_options,
}
```

Or you can save some code if you put the `mysql_name` value under a different hiera key:

```
$override_options = {
  hiera('mysql_name') => hiera('web_mysql_server')
}
```

---

*Original answer*:

If your actual intention is just to create a configuration file, the best way is using [templates](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template.html) in [erb syntax](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template_erb.html).

Here is an example. First, you put a `my.cnf.erb` file to the `templates` directory of your module (e.g. `modules/web_mysql/templates`):

```
[<%= @mysql_config['mysql_name'] %>]
adaptor =  mysql2
database = <%= @mysql_config['mysql_database'] %>
user     = <%= @mysql_config['mysql_username'] %>
password = <%= @mysql_config['mysql_password'] %>
host     = 0.0.0.0
encoding = UTF8
```

You can use this template in your `web_mysql::mysql_server` class to create the config file:

```
class web_mysql::mysql_server {
  # ...
  $mysql_config = hiera('web_mysql_server')
  file { '/etc/mysql/my.cnf':
    ensure  => 'present',
    content => template('web_mysql/my.cnf.erb'),
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using `web_mysql::mysql_server` indicates that the class has a *parameter* called `production`. If that is the case you have to use that name when you use the class. Instead, why not just call the parameter `mysql` or `client`, since it seems to be the client configuration parameter?

---

Answer to original question:

Neither version of your manifest is valid Puppet. For example, putting this in my manifest:

```
'production' => {
  adaptor  => 'mysql2',
}
```

and running `puppet apply --noop --modulepath modules manifests/host.pp` results in:

```
Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '=>' at [...]/host.pp:1:14 on node hostname
```

Did you mean to say something like this?

```
$database_configuration = {
  adaptor  => 'mysql2',
  database => $mysql_config['mysql_database'],
  user     => $mysql_config['mysql_username'],
  password => $mysql_config['mysql_password'],
  host     => '0.0.0.0',
  encoding => 'UTF8',
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think @Mifeet was correct to request that I add the surrounding code.  Does it make more sense now?